# Hibernate Criteria could not resolve property when it's there

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

This one has me stumped.  I have an idea how criteria works but for some reason this query is giving me issues not being able to find a property when it's clearly there.

Shelf.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOKSHELF")
public class Shelf {

@Id
private int shelfId;
private String shelfName;
private String shelfType;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="shelf",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Book> book = new HashSet<Book>(0);

//getters&setters here
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BOOKS")
public class Book {

@Id
private int bookId;
private String bookName;
private String bookState;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Shelf shelf;    

//getters&setters here
```

Here's my criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("shelf.shelfId", bookLocId))
                    .add(Restrictions.ne("shelf.shelfType", "table"))
                    .add(Restrictions.ne("bookState", "requested");
```

The problem is the middle restriction.  It can't find `shelfType` but it finds `shelfId` just fine.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It finds `shelfId` just fine, because it is the key of the association and therefore there is no join required for the query to see the ID. If you want to add restriction to other property, you must JOIN the `shelf` association, for instance like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Book.class)
         // JOINs shelf association and creates alias 'shelf' for it
         .createAlias("shelf", "shelf")
         .add(Restrictions.eq("shelf.shelfId", bookLocId))
         .add(Restrictions.ne("shelf.shelfType", "table"))
         .add(Restrictions.ne("bookState", "requested");
```

Comment: Thank you Bohuslav!  That worked great.  I did look into the `.createAlias` but maybe I didn't use it right the first time.  Thanks again.  Now it's more clear.